# How can I enumerate Google Groups in my domain and list their members?

Tags: java, google-api, gdata, gdata-api, google-api-java-client

I want to enumerate the groups (and their members) that are available on my Google Apps For Business domain, but I am having problems finding relevant API. Everything available on the [documentation page](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#groupssettings) seems to assume I already know the group name - and even then there's no way to list the members.

The previous version of the API, gdata, has a [clear interface](http://code.google.com/intl/pl/googleapps/domain/gdata_provisioning_api_v2.0_reference_java.html) for everything that I intend to do - but it does not provide a Maven package (in fact it explicitly states that [no such package will be provided](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/issues/detail?id=59)) and the development team is [suggesting that the new interface is preferable](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/wiki/MigratingToGoogleApiJavaClient).

So is it possible to enumerate groups using Google API the same way it was possible with GDATA API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out how to do this. Basic code, including authentication:

```
public class GroupLister {
    static HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();
    static HttpParser parser = new AtomParser(new XmlNamespaceDictionary());

    public GroupFeed listGroups(String domainName, String apiKey,
            String username, String password) throws IOException {
        HttpRequestFactory factory = createRequestFactory(transport, username,
                password);
        GoogleUrl url = new GoogleUrl(
                "https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/group/2.0/" + domainName);
        url.key = apiKey;
        return factory.buildGetRequest(url).execute().parseAs(GroupFeed.class);
    }

    public HttpRequestFactory createRequestFactory(
            final HttpTransport transport, final String username,
            final String password) {
        return transport.createRequestFactory(new HttpRequestInitializer() {
            public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
                request.addParser(parser);
                ClientLogin authenticator = new ClientLogin();
                authenticator.transport = transport;
                authenticator.authTokenType = "apps";
                authenticator.username = username;
                authenticator.password = password;
                request.getHeaders().setAuthorization(
                        authenticator.authenticate()
                                .getAuthorizationHeaderValue());
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Data classes:

```
public class GroupFeed {
    @Key
    public Date updated;
    @Key("entry")
    public List<GroupEntry> groups;
}

public class GroupEntry {
    @Key
    public String id;
    @Key("apps:property")
    public List<PropertyEntry> properties;
}

public class PropertyEntry {
    @Key("@name")
    public String name;
    @Key("@value")
    public String value;
}
```

This took a lot of trial & error attempts.